# How to get rid of the quote marks from a dict key/value pair?

Tags: python, printing, yaml

I have a script that parses a yaml file and extracts key/value pairs and prints them, but I keep getting single quotes in the output.

How do I get rid of the quote marks?

**YML Snippet**

```
AsNum:
  description: Local AS for BGP global
  format: string
  type: string
```

**Function from Script**

```
def getVals(dict):
    for key,value in dict.items():
        #print(keys)
        if isDict(value):
            if key != "properties"  and key != "items":
                print(key)
            getVals(value)
        else:
            print("key: ", key, "  value: ", value)
```

**Example Output**

```
AsNum
('key: ', 'type', '  value: ', 'string')
('key: ', 'description', '  value: ', 'Local AS for BGP global')
('key: ', 'format', '  value: ', 'string')
```

Comment: `print("key: {} value: {}".format(key,value))`

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of that question. The reason that this OP gets the output he gets, is because he is printing tuples with the `print` statement in Python2. This is best solved by inserting `from _future__ import print_function` a the top of the program, then you get the `print` function and the output the OP expects.